# Java portlet settings

Tags: java, settings, portlet

I'm building a java portlet (JSR-168) application and want to define settings, which only the portal administrator can access/change. What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define settings in the `<portlet-preferences>` section of the `portlet.xml` of your portlet.

Something like (copied from the spec)

```
<portlet>
...
<!—- Portlet Preferences -->
<portlet-preferences>
    <preference>
        <name>PreferredStockSymbols</name>
        <value>FOO</value>
        <value>XYZ</value>
        <read-only>false</read-only>
    </preference>
    ...
</portlet-preferences>
</portlet>
```

This is a very *standard* way of doing it. Most portlet servers allow administrators to change the value of the properties' portlet from the *administration zone* of the server. This depends on the vendor, as it is not specified in the specification.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed with using Jahia that the preference section that you just get teh default value, after that it can get changed and stored in the preferences, but only for the lifetime of the deployment of the portlet.